# I have a Typeform opened in the Android app webview. proceeding to fill the typeform inside the webview is crashing the app in Android pie

Tags: java, android, android-webview, typeform

I have a Typeform opened in the Android webview. Whenever I select to proceed (Ex: continue button) to fill the typeform inside the webview, app crashes, and re-opens. Error in the logs is as follows "Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed". How to fix the issue?

```
2019-10-04 17:20:30.098 19393-19621/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x54 in tid 19621 (Chrome_InProcGp), pid 19393 (.APPNAME.debug)
2019-10-04 17:20:30.088 19393-19486/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus6/OnePlus6:9/PKQ1.180716.001/1909112330:user/release-keys'
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG: pid: 19393, tid: 19621, name: Chrome_InProcGp  >>> com.APPNAME.debug <<<
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x54
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000007c71114f00  x1  0000000000000000  x2  000000000000000f  x3  0000000000000017
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     x4  0000007c54ada168  x5  0000007c54ada140  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000007c56100c20
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     x8  0000000000000000  x9  0000000000000020  x10 0000000000000001  x11 000000000000001c
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000000000000000  x14 0000007c54846980  x15 00000000fffffe24
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     x16 0000007c6bcf4ef0  x17 00000000ffffffb8  x18 0000000000000001  x19 0000007c569d5080
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000007c71114f00  x21 0000007c54adca00  x22 0000000000000000  x23 0000007c6c0564a8
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000000000000001  x25 0000000000000001  x26 0000000000000001  x27 0000000000000000
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000007c565f0320
2019-10-04 17:20:30.286 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     sp  0000007c565f0230  lr  0000007c6bdcf5a0  pc  0000007c6bcf4ef0
2019-10-04 17:20:30.295 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-10-04 17:20:30.295 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000023bef0  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A6xResource::HwValidateSubResource(EsxSubResource const*))
2019-10-04 17:20:30.295 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000031659c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxTextureObject::MapExternalResource(EsxContext*, EsxResource*, EsxDimensionType, int)+1948)
2019-10-04 17:20:30.295 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000000000241f7c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A6xContext::ValidateFbFetchMemObjsForTexLocation(unsigned int, EsxFramebufferAttachmentType)+444)
2019-10-04 17:20:30.295 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000039d8e4  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A6xContext::ValidateFramebufferFetchTexSamplers(EsxPipeline const*, EsxFramebufferObject const*)+204)
2019-10-04 17:20:30.295 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000000000038fb98  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A6xContext::ValidateState(EsxDrawDescriptor const*)+456)
2019-10-04 17:20:30.295 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0000000000252318  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::ValidateGfxState(EsxDrawDescriptor const*)+864)
2019-10-04 17:20:30.295 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00000000002c4938  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::DrawArraysInstanced(EsxPrimType, int, unsigned int, unsigned int)+200)
2019-10-04 17:20:30.295 19673-19673/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000000000224a9e8  /data/app/com.android.chrome-WfRfeLGaqR2hubD9QXAI-Q==/base.apk (offset 0xc19000)
2019-10-04 17:20:30.994 979-979/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_01

`webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(progressView)); 
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(progressView)); 
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); 
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE); 
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true); 
webView.loadUrl(mUrl);`
```

Comment: Maybe showing some of your code would help!

Comment: try disabling hardware acceleration in the webview webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);